# Improving performance while loading clob column in an Oracle table from a varchar(max) column in a SQL Server table when using pentaho data integrator

Tags: sql-server, oracle, clob, pentaho-data-integration

I am trying to load several millions of records from a SQL Server table (that has couple of integer columns and a `varchar(max)` column) into an Oracle table of identical structure where a clob column gets the `varchar(max)` text.

The ETL tool that I am using is Pentaho data integration (PDI) using a simple transformation. When running the transformation, the record read/write speed is 150r/s. But when I did not include CLOB column in table output step, the speed is 5000r/s. Is there any way to improve the target write speed?

Comment: The varcharmax field has text with length of tens of thousands.

Answer (score 0):

Well actualy I could bet is not a target issue, else, is a source issue. Take in count that a text with the size of clob must be a big text!, so, extracting it from the source could be the problem.

You can try "Text File Output" to write the content to a text file, and then send it to the target database. In some cases, establishing a batch size helps you to improve the insert scenario. All depends in the steps you are using to achieve your goal.